# How are proofs normally constructed in a write up, in one line or split up into multiple lines?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting

Here is the same proof formatted two different ways. My questions is what is the standard for a writeup like a homework assignment? I think the first one looks better but I don't think that is the way that I normally see it. If someone could just say which one is better I would really appreciate it.

[image: Line by line]
[image: not line by line]

Here is the code for the latex for the first output.

```
\subsection*{13.}
\subsubsection*{(a)}
In order to show $f(A_1 \cup A_2) = f(A_1)\cup f(A_2)$, we want to show $f(A_1 \cup A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$ and $f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)$. 
\\
Let $y \in f(A_1 \cup A_2)$. 
\\
Then there exists a $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$ such that $f(x) = y$. 
\\
If $x \in A_1$, then $y \in f(A_1)$. 
\\
As a result, $y \in f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$. 
\\
If $x \in A_2$, then $y \in f(A_2)$. 
\\
So, $y \in f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$. 
\\
Therefore, $f(A_1 \cup A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$. 
\\
\\
Moreover, we want to show $f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)$. 
\\
Let $y \in f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$. 
\\
If $y \in f(A_1)$, then there exists a $x \in A_1$ such that $f(x) = y$. 
\\
Since $x \in A_1$, then $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$. 
\\
If $y \in f(A_2)$, then there exists a $x \in A_2$ such that $f(x) = y$. 
\\
Since $x \in A_2$, then $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$. 
\\
As a result $y \in f(A_1 \cup A_2)$. 
\\
Therefore, $f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)$. 
\\
Since $f(A_1 \cup A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$ and $f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)$, we can conclude that $f(A_1 \cup A_2) = f(A_1)\cup f(A_2)$.
```

Comment: As someone who has taught a bit, I'd prefer the first approach as there is more space for marking it up or adding comments. However, I'd suggest asking your teacher since their opinion counts more.

Comment: I agree with @DJP and I would also use some displaymath every now and then. Could you please add a minimal example of the code you used to produce the output shown?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use `\\` to go to a new line, if you need a new line use `\newline`, if you need a new paragraph, leave a blank line. Use `\\` only in tabulars.
2. Why are you naming you `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` instead of letting LaTeX do it for you? Is it to match the homework numbers or only because you can't modify the numbering layout?

This is what I would do. Of course, I don't know the topic, so you can improve it putting the displaymath where it is really needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{13.}% Why are you numbering the section and don't let LaTeX do it for you? 
\subsubsection*{(a)}
In order to show \[f(A_1 \cup A_2) = f(A_1)\cup f(A_2)\] we want to show \[f(A_1 \cup A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \quad \text{and} \quad f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)\,\text{.}\] 

Let $y \in f(A_1 \cup A_2)$. 
Then there exists a $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$ such that $f(x) = y$.
If $x \in A_1$, then $y \in f(A_1)$. 
As a result, \[y \in f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)\,\text{.}\] 
If $x \in A_2$, then $y \in f(A_2)$. 
So, $y \in f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$. 
Therefore, \[f(A_1 \cup A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)\,\text{.}\] 

Moreover, we want to show \[f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)\,\text{.}\] 

Let $y \in f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$. 
If $y \in f(A_1)$, then there exists a $x \in A_1$ such that $f(x) = y$. 
Since $x \in A_1$, then $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$. 
If $y \in f(A_2)$, then there exists a $x \in A_2$ such that $f(x) = y$. 
Since $x \in A_2$, then $x \in A_1 \cup A_2$. 
As a result \[y \in f(A_1 \cup A_2)\,\text{.}\]

Therefore, \[f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)\,\text{.}\]

Since $f(A_1 \cup A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cup f(A_2)$ and $f(A_1) \cup f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cup A_2)$, we can conclude that \[f(A_1 \cup A_2) = f(A_1)\cup f(A_2)\,\text{.}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks really good. Yes I need the numbering to match specific problems in my homework. I appreciate the feedback and will be using your suggestions.

Comment: @JacFrall I'm happy you like it, thanks!